# Install Plugin via Code

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm working with a hook that is fired after a site has been added to a management portal, is there a way of install plugins through code, from url?

Answer (score 0):

There is something wonderfull call [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org/), that is wordpress from the terminal.
I dont know how it works on windows, but if it isnt possible to install on cmd or powershell, windows already have the ubuntu terminal, that is great for this kind of stuff.

e.g. to install iControlWP:

```
wp plugin install iControlWP
```

simple as that!..

[iControlWP](https://icontrolwp.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/3000039306-how-to-install-new-plugins-from-a-public-link-url) is one plugin that do just that.